# Failed To Compile New Angular Project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

I created a new Angular project through `ng new`.

But whenever i try to compile it through `ng serve`, it keeps showing these three errors in the terminal window.

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:/C#/CCC/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in '[Path]'
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'F:\C#\CCC\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&reconnect=10' in '[Path]'
Error: The loader "F:/C#/CCC/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really was the **character '#'** in the folder's name **in the project path**, after removing it, the problem was solved.

Modification should be as below,

From:

```
"F:/C#/CCC/src/app/app.component.css"
```

to

```
"F:/CSharp/CCC/src/app/app.component.css"
```

Directory name called "C#" should be modified by eliminating #

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, i found that the problem is in the project path (the **'#'** character).

I changed it to **CSharp** instead of **C#** and it worked.